# Linux (2.6.19) запуск SSH сервера

Tags: linux, ssh

Здравствуйте возникла необходимость подключаться pytty к удаленному серверу на Linux (платформа на ARM проце).
Там должен уже быть запущен SSH сервер, но после нескольких попыток подключится, я решил проверить непосредственно на сервере запушен ли там SSH.

1. Версия linux

   # unname -mrs

   Linux 2.6.19 armv5tel
2. Проверка открытых портов (LISTEN)

   netstat -a

[image: netstat -a]

3. Проверка запущенных процессов

   ps

[image: ps]

4. Попытка запуска/останова процесса

   /etc/init.d/ssh start

[image: ssh start stop]

5. Файл конфигурации SSH
   etc/ssh/sshd_config
   Из раскомментированных строк только:

> Port 22
>
> Protocol 2,1
>
> ListenAddress 0.0.0.0

Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так, как запустить SSH сервер?

Comment: *missing privilege separation directory: /var/empty* — так создайте его.

Comment: пРОСТО ПОПРОБОВАТЬ СОЗАДТЬ ПУСТУЮ ПАПКУ?

Comment: заработалло!!! спасибо